# ionic-Cordova-ios : could not change the origin for ios app

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-ios, angular-social-login, ionic-cordova

I m developing hybrid application in ionic with angular where in my cordova-ios app we are trying to implement firebase social login authentication. my ios app origin is "ionic://localhost/#/login" so that firebase does not allows this origin and it throws cors error.

I have tried following steps but nothing improvement

1. added meta information in index.html file .
2. in the config.xml file changed the preference
3. Changed the webview plugin to wkwebview and UIwebview

In firebase i could not make allow this origin ionic://localhost/#/login so that i think it should be change the origin in app itself.

provide me a solutions to resolve it . Thanks in advance.